# Launch a .bat from Jenkins does not work

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, android-emulator, appium

This is the .bat file :

```
start cmd.exe /k "C:\Users\etudes.ext46\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -avd ff &"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60 > nul
start cmd.exe /k "adb shell input keyevent 82"
start cmd.exe /k "node "C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 &"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 30 > nul
C:\Users\etudes.ext46\Downloads\NUnit-2.6.4\NUnit-2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe C:\Users\etudes.ext46\Downloads\NUnit-2.6.4\NUnit-2.6.4\bin\apk\UnitTestProject1.dll
start cmd.exe /k "taskkill /F /IM emulator-x86.exe"
start cmd.exe /k "taskkill /F /IM node.exe"
start cmd.exe /k "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe"
```

When i run it manually, it works pretty well (emulate an android device an use Appium with Nunit tests).

But when I try to launch the **exact** same .bat from Jenkins it doesn't work

```
Errors and Failures:
1) TearDown Error : AppiumSample.ASSI2.AssistanceV2
   SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.) (33)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The complete logs are here : http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/KsrEJiT.png

How can I make this .bat work with Jenkins?

Comment: The link to the log does not work. I would start by verifying that the user has the proper permissions when run from Jenkins. Also, use full path for all executables, as the current directory may be different when run from Jenkins (adb and node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the option `-no-window` when launching the emulator

```
start cmd.exe /k "C:\path\emulator.exe -avd ff -no-window &"
```

instead of

```
start cmd.exe /k "C:\path\emulator.exe -avd ff &"
```